# Surface view android Threads

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview

Do I need to create a Thread to handle the drawing on SurfaceView, or it is automatically created by Android? I am drawing just some circles, without moving.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a thread unless you really want to create one thread ( if you are building a simple game of some kind, for the game loop you may have to create a Thread which calls the onDraw() method forever :) )

find More about game loops in this [tutorial](http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame3.html)

Comment: You generally don't want to override `onDraw()` in a SurfaceView. The linked tutorial is broken.